# Annotation order in @Entity classes in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, annotations

Might sound like a funny question but I couldn't find an answer elsewhere: does the order of annotations on the fields of an @Entity class matter?

I'm talking about annotations like

```
@Column(name = "password")
@Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
@Transient
private String password;
```

or

```
@Column(name = "created_at", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
@CreationTimestamp 
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdAt;
```

Comment: No. it doesn't matter.

Comment: Er, no? Are you trying to do something in particular, like apply particular semantics based on the order of the annotations or something? Like, are you trying to ensure that the length validation comes before the not-empty validation?

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
No, I am more interested in any potential side effects or if there are some sorts of conventions (good coding style).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functionally, the order doesn't matter.
From a reading perspective of course it matters.
As you look a entity field you want to know straight general things about.
Its mapping in the DB for example or the collection relationship used.

Generally this question matters as you need to declare a certain number of annotations for a same field (at least 4 as in your example).

Some good sense ideas :

- they should be consistently specified in the code between entities
- make more visible the most general annotations (`@Column`, `@ManyToOne` and so for) than the most specific (validation annotations for example)
- group related annotations. For example annotations related to validation  should be grouped and similarly annotations related to association with another entity should also be grouped.

From general to specific and validations together :

```
@Column(name = "pass")
@Transient
@Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
private String password;
```

Or from specific to general and validations together :

```
@Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
@Transient
@Column(name = "pass")
private String password;
```

appear more readable as a messy order :

```
@Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
@Column(name = "pass")
@Transient
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
private String password;
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is better to follow the order established in this table:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/toplink-jpa-annotations-096251.html

Following your example, it might be:

```
@Column(name = "password")
@Transient
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "created_at", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@CreationTimestamp 
private Date createdAt;
```

But as I know, There is no established convention for it

Comment: Thanks for the link, Mayte.